# Dialogflow and Push notification

Tags: push-notification, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm actually implementing the push notification (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) and I'm not sure to understand everything.

I'm using dialogflow through webhook json with php webservices, and meant to be used with google home (and phone).
All my tests are done through simulator.

I've created an intent get_store

I've created 2 implicits intents (notification_store and notification_text)  and activated them as notification in the action console.

When I go into get_store, i'm asking a permission to send notification for notification_store (to send a gmap link), when the user respond yes, it returns me an UPDATES_USER_ID and set the user permission as true in all next requests.
Then, I use this UPDATES_USER_ID and the get_store to send the notification (it responds with a 200 ok)

Questions : 
 - Once I've accepted the permission, it will not ask me any new permission, even if I want to send notification for notification_text, which means it's one update permission for all notifications intents?
 - I can't delete UpdatePermission from my user, even after using reset button or change version
 - I have a doubt, does it work only with a released version (alpha/beta/prod) or even with a draft?

If someone can help me to understand what's possible so I could be able to know what is working, not working, not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: was this to run on a google home / smart speaker? I'm trying to find a way to push a notification to a users phone after an interaction with google home.

Comment: Hello, indeed, my project was on a google home speaker and I was using notifications to send extra informations on the phone (like a google map link). But finally, notifications wasn't the good thing to do, instead, I'd use the mutl surface conversation : https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask for permission to send push notifications, the **UPDATE** permission gets cached so you don't have to repeatedly ask the user for permission. However this permission is unique to the intent specified when asking for permission.

When asking for a user's permission to send push notifications, you must specify the implicit intent you are asking permission for. So in **get_store**, I imagine this intent is set to **notification_store**.

The following code uses the Node.js client library, but the concept is the same:

```
app.intent('get_store', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new UpdatePermission({intent: 'notification_store'}));
});
```

Because of this, you can't use **get_store** to ask for permission for **notification_text**. Instead you will need to create a separate intent such as **get_text**, which specifically asks for permission to send push notifications for **notification_text**.

Comment: After playing a lot with that, apparently, when you ask an update permission, it will return you a user token id. Then, you'll have to use this token for any intent notifications. You need only one request for an UPDATE permission.